# null in console after submit button in router.post

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, contact-form

This here is my form where i'm trying to redirect the page to home after hitting the submit button! `res.redirect('/home')` is not working so I have tried to do that with `console.log("testing");` and for some reason that is not working as well! What am I missing?

Comment: fs.writeFile is an asynchronous function, please look into how asynchronous works in js

Comment: I think removing `onclick` attribute will solve your problem it is stopping the form from submitting.

Answer (score 1):

1)Consider using form's onsubmit method instead of button's onclick. Just because it's made for that purpose. 2)There are alot of code but redirect is nowhere to be found. 3)There is no reason to redirect on client on submitting the form. Just none. You should submit it to the server, receive the data, and then redirect, if you want.

```
router.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    //do something
});

router.post('/contact/send', function(req, res){
    console.log("testingggg");
    res.redirect('/home');
});
```

Also, dont name your API '/contact/send', just '/contact' is enough.